# Sliding an image into view using skrollr

Tags: css, skrollr

I have a div that sits centralised on the page which has text with an image aligned to the right, as shown below.  The problem I'm experiencing is getting the image to slide into view from the right when the user scrolls down and brings the region into view.

I'm able to change the opacity successfully but I'm not able to get it working for how I need, i.e. moving the image from right to left by 50 pixels.

I'm experimenting with the skrollr library.  Any suggestions where I'm going wrong please?

Many thanks,
James

**code example**

```
<div>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse lorem felis, ultricies vitae justo sed, rutrum sagittis quam. Cras sodales metus odio, eu rhoncus elit commodo a
   <img src="test.png" align="right" />
</div>
```

**CSS for the div**

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-left: -485px;
    width: 970px;
}
```

**JS**

```
var s = skrollr.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to give your image the skrller data, something like:

```
<img style=opacity:0 class="skrollable unrendered" data-bottom-top=right:400px; data-top=right:0; alt="" />
```

Of course you'll need to adjust to your needs, but the point is that for EVERY element you need to apply the Skrller behavior, you need to give it some data

Comment: you have to ADJUST the code, it was placed as an example since I don't know what do you want/need. But the bottom line is you need to read the Skrollr tutorial so you understand how do elements work. If you don't add any data, the element will remain unchanged (or even worse, invisible)